# How to create dynamic Jlist in java when jlist height is dependent on number of Rows in List?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, netbeans-8

[image]I am creating a jlist in java where I want to be height of list to be dynamic according to number of rows in the list:

- I mean when there are no rows in the list, it should not show that empty list box, (I want to set jlist minimum height to be 0)
- I want to set the maximum height of list to be fixed, when the rows exceed that maximum height it should start scrolling the jlist
- when the list occupies a smaller height than the maximum height size, it should only show up to those space which were occupied by rows (I mean no empty space should be shown on the list)

I've already created a jlist, but it is showing empty space when the number of rows occupies a smaller space than the maximum list space height.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size based on your requirements.

But first you would need to do:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(???);
```

This will allow the default preferred size calculation to calculate the size of your list before the scrollbars appear.

Then you need to modify the `getPreferredSize()` method of the `JList`. It might look something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

    int rows = getModel().getSize();

    if (rows < getVisibleRowCount())
    {
        int rowHeight = d.height / getVisibleRowCount();
        d.height = rows * rowHeight;
    }

    return d;
}
```

Comment: i am not good in gui design in java. i am using netbeans as drag and drop, i dropped jlist in jframe, rest work is done by netbeans... i am not underStanding how to override this getPreferredSize() function...

Comment: @HemantDhanuka, If you don't know how to override a method of a class then you should not be using the GUI designer. I have never used a GUI designer so I can't tell you how to do it. I would rather spend my time learning Java, not the IDE. If you ever switch to a different IDE then your code will not be maintainable in the other IDE. So I recommend you just use the IDE to aid in compiling and debugging, but not for generating forms or code.